# What does "table that is a parent of a referential integrity constraint" in regards to oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm preparing for the Oracle 1Z0-051 exam and I read this in [a question about `DELETE/TRUNCATE`](http://www.aiotestking.com/oracle/which-two-statements-are-true-regarding-the-delete-and-truncate-commands/):

> ... table that is a parent of a referential integrity constraint ...

What does it mean for a table to be a "parent" of a another table that has referential integrity constraint?

Or perhaps this is a false positive in the answer choices?

Comment: I'm not good on terminology, so this is a guess: referential integrity constraints are used to ensure that relationships between tables can be maintained (e.g. if you have a CustomerType table and a Customer table with field CustomerTypeId with a foreign key reference to the CustomerType table, the CustomerType would be the parent of the constraint (i.e. because one type may have multiple customers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"parent" and "child" are commonly used when describing the two tables in a one-to-many relationship (of any kind, not just database related). A "parent" has many "children" (rows).

The "parent" is the table referred *to* in a foreign key constraint.
The "child" is the table referring *to* the parent in a foreign key constraint.

eg

```
create table customer ( -- the "parent"
  id int,
  ...
  primary key (id)
)

create table cart ( -- the "child"
    id int,
    customer_id int,  -- the foreign key column
    ...
    constraint foreign key (customer_id) references customer(id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Referential Integrity is implemented via a Foreign Key.  The parent, is the table being referenced.  So if I had an Employee table and a Department table, my foreign key would say the dept_id in the Employee table (child) must exist in the Department table (parent).

[Referential Integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)